# Unable to write data to the control of other from in VC++ winforms

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, picturebox

I am trying to show an image on the pictureBox of the second Form from First Form.
But I am not able to see any output....

My Code of Form1.cpp is like this

```
#include "SecondForm.h"

SecondForm^ obj=gcnew SecondForm();
System::Drawing::Bitmap ^bmp = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(grf->width,grf->height,grf->widthStep,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)grf->imageData);
obj->pictureBox1->Image=obj->pictureBox1->Image->FromHbitmap(bmp->GetHbitmap());
```

I don't know what is the problem.....

Can anybody please help me sort our this problem...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are creating a *new* form object, you can't see it because you didn't call its Show() method.  I'll have to guess that you didn't actually want to do that.  Store the reference in a field of your class so you can use it later.  Use Application::OpenForms only if you get desperate.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Thanks for your reply.... You are right.. I am giving obj->show() before this Image code then I am able to see my Image. But actually I want to write Image on pictureBox before showing second form because My image is coming on run time while processing form1 and I want to see Image on the second form when I click on the button of form1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this simple code -

```
obj.pictureBox1.Image = bmp; // [You may write the C++ equivalent]
```

Instead of this -

> obj->pictureBox1->Image=obj->pictureBox1->Image->FromHbitmap(bmp->GetHbitmap());

Comment: Thanks for reply... using the code which i have pasted I am able to display image on the current form but not able to display on the other form..